# Detect If Device / Browser Supports Fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

How can one tell if a browser supports FullScreen API in JavaScript?

From my understanding, the latest Safari allows it on iPads and not iPhone.

I am wondering how I can detect if the device supports it so I can conditionally show or hide a fullscreen button.

(Ideally in Angular using TypeScript)

Comment: `document.fullscreenEnabled` ?

Comment: Lol I don't know how I missed that in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> **[document.fullscreenEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenEnabled)**
>
> The fullscreenEnabled property tells you whether or not it is possible to engage full-screen mode. This is false if full-screen mode is not available for any reason (such as the "fullscreen" feature not being allowed, or full-screen mode not being supported).